# [C++14]I'm using pair but no output

Tags: c++, sorting, c++14, std-pair

I was writing a code to sort and output the number by using "pair".
I tried some cases bat there was no output.
How should I rewrite the code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int k, i, n;
    cin >> n;
    pair<int, int> a[n];
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> k;
        a[i].first = -k;
        a[i].second = i + 1;
    }
    sort(a, a + n);
    for (i = 0; i++; i < n) {
        cout << a[i].second;
    }
}
```

Comment: Turn up your warnings: *warning: for increment expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]*

Answer (score 4):

```
for(i=0;i++;i<n){
```

You meant to write this as:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
```

Comment: Thank you!
Input is difficult…

Comment: @YasushiMatsushima if the answer is correct please consider marking it as "Accepted"